# 'More encountered' or 'encountered more'?

Tags: word-choice, differences

> The prevalence of respiratory allergy was **more encountered** among females.

In this sentence, would we use *more encountered* or *encountered more*. Do they both mean the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

I found using Google Ngrams that *encountered more* is [used more commonly and yields more search results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+encountered%2C+encountered+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20encountered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cencountered%20more%3B%2Cc0), but I could not understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Before addressing the placement of 'more', I'd recommend that you consider rephrasing. I'd use 'Respiratory allergy was found to be more common among females...' unless someone pointed out I'd obscured a deeper meaning. //  'Nargles were more seen in females' would be a wrong positioning of 'more'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different errors in this sentence, regardless of the order of the two mentioned words.

First, the idea behind “more encountered” or “encountered more” must be expressed as “encountered more often”, as you clearly mean the *frequency* of encounters and not degree or intensity. Second, this expression is redundant, as the concept is already expressed by the word “prevalence”. The two grammatical alternatives are:

A: “The prevalence of respiratory allergy was greater among females” (preserving “prevalence”)

B: “Respiratory allergy was encountered more often among females” (preserving “encountered”)